# cancel AsyncTask class in android

Tags: android, eclipse

I have two buttons.  The first one to start mediaplayer and the second to cancel it:
mediaplayer is in `AsyncTask` and i use( thread -while) to repeat it
I need the mediaplayer to play until the user presses cancel 
when i start it is running and when i press cancel it stops( When i do not go out the page-layout-,)

```
private DoSomething doSomething;
    @Override   
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.first);
final MediaPlayer mp;
mp=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.ab);

//===================================================
    final Button first=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final Button second=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    first.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) { 
            //start your asynctask
           if(doSomething == null || doSomething.isCancelled()){
            doSomething = new DoSomething();
                doSomething = (DoSomething) doSomething.execute();
           }  }
    });

    second.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
   doSomething.cancel(true);

        }  });}
```

The problem: when i go out the layout and return to  cancel the asynctask there is aproblem in

```
doSomething.cancel(true);
```

Because null pointer   the doSomething see asyntask not running while it run

I use `Status g=doSomething.getStatus();`
it is PENDING not RUNNING

```
class DoSomething extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        while(true){
            if(isCancelled()){
                break;
            }
            final MediaPlayer mp;
            mp=MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.ab);


                        mp.start();
                        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                mp.release();
                            }
                        });

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(8 * 1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace()  }}
        return null;
    }}
```

Comment: why do you need an AsyncTask?

Comment: A couple of comments: 1. You're using 2 users to ask a question. That's really confusing. 2. You need to learn to add comments instead of answers to your question. 3. Post your logcat

Comment: Look at my corrected answer

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to solve your problem is to change your second click to

```
second.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
          if(doSomething != null && !doSomething.isCancelled()){
              doSomething.cancel(true);
        }  
    })
;
```

Comment: we can use like this also http://www.quicktips.in/correct-way-to-cancel-an-asynctask-in-android/